# Implement 'Select All' option in reactive shiny

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, interactive, selectall

I'm building a shiny app which displays a table based on user selections. I have a table called 'stat' and it is of the form

```
Team      Season   wins  loss  draws
Arsenal   1992-93   18    12    14
Arsenal   1993-94   21    10    7 
Liverpool 1992-93   22    6     12
Liverpool 1993-94   19    13    10
 All        All     0     0     0
```

I need to filter the data based on the team and season selected. The table should display all season's data when 'All' is selected for season and vice versa for team.

I had tried some of the code below but it's not working as expected.

```
#UI part
selectInput("club", "Select Club", choices = stat$Team),
                 selectInput("season", "Select Season", choices = 
 stat$Season)

#server part
server <- output$statdata <- renderTable({
  teamfilter <- subset(stat, (stat$Team == input$club) & 
                         (stat$Season==input$season))
})

  observe({
    if("Select All" %in% input$club)
      selected_choices = stat$Team[-1]
    else
      selected_choices = input$club
    updateSelectInput(session, "club", selected = selected_choices)

})
```

Can some suggest me a correct code or tell me if any changes are required to make the code working.

Comment: How about `input$club == "All" | stat$Team == input$club`?

Comment: @r2evans Didn't work. I believe the error is mainly in the observe function.

Comment: @Prajwal  IN the UI, you need `tableOutput('statdata')`  Also, may be `output$statdata <- renderTable({
        if(input$season == "All") {
            subset(stat, Team != "All")
            
        } else 
       subset(stat, (Team == input$club) & 
                                 (Season==input$season))
    })`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a full-working example showing how one might incorporate "All" into a `selectInput`:

```r
library(shiny)
dat <- mtcars
app <- shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(
    pageWithSidebar(
      headerPanel("Simple Test"),
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("cyl", "Cylinders", choices = c("All", sort(unique(dat$cyl)))),
        selectInput("gear", "Gears", choices = c("All", sort(unique(dat$gear))))
      ),
      mainPanel(
        shiny::tableOutput("out")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    filtered <- reactive({
      rows <- (input$cyl == "All" | dat$cyl == input$cyl) &
        (input$gear == "All" | dat$gear == input$gear)
      dat[rows,,drop = FALSE]
    })
    output$out <- renderTable(filtered())
  }
)
```

This takes advantage of R's recycling: while `input$gear == "All"` returns a single logical, `dat$gear == input$gear` returns a vector as long as the number of rows in the table. Because the first logical is length 1, it is recycled as long as the second vector. This means that `input$gear == "All"` is effectively a vector of length "nrow(dat)", and is always all `TRUE` or all `FALSE`. When true, none of the other `$gear` comparisons matter (I'm glossing over `NA` comparisons); when false, the other `$gear` comparisons are relevant.

Demonstration of recycling:

```r
1 == 1
# [1] TRUE
1 == 2
# [1] FALSE

1 == 1:5
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

1 == 1 | 1 == 1:5
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
1 == 2 | 1 == 1:5
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```